filter on union entities with JPA specification
Considering this java JPA model:
  @Entity
  @Table(name = "PARENT")
  @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
  public abstract class ParentEntity { }

  @Entity
  @Table(name = "PARENT_Child1")
  public abstract class Child1Entity extends ParentEntity  { }

  @Entity
  @Table(name = "PARENT_Child2")
  public abstract class Child2Entity extends ParentEntity { }

  @Entity
  @Table(name = "PARENT_Child3")
  public abstract class Child3Entity extends ParentEntity { }

A call from spring data JPA repository like:
parentRepository.findAll(specification);

will generate this query:
select parent.id, from (select id from PARENT union all select id 1 as clazz_ from PARENT_CHILD1 union all select id, 2 as clazz_ from PARENT_CHILD2 union all select id, 3 as clazz_ from PARENT_CHILD3) parent

which is what I expected. But I am looking for a way to limit the union to only some child type, like only Child2Entity and Child1Entity but not Child3Entity.
Is this possible using JPA specification?
In JPA, I don't have union keyword to write plain hql query.

To limit the UNION operation to specific child types when using the TABLE_PER_CLASS inheritance strategy in JPA, you can modify the query by selecting from each table individually and then using the IN clause to filter only the desired child types.
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder(); 
CriteriaQuery<ParentEntity> query = cb.createQuery(ParentEntity.class); 
Root<ParentEntity> root = query.from(ParentEntity.class); 
List<Class<? extends ParentEntity>> subclasses = Arrays.asList(Child1Entity.class, Child2Entity.class); 
query.select(root).where(root.type().in(subclasses));
List<ParentEntity> result = entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList();**


It doesnt avoid une union fetch but it work by adding a in clause. Thanks

I add for posterity, a JPA specification implementation of the jpa criteria @A RAM 's answer.
List<Class<? extends ParentEntity>> subclasses = Arrays.asList(Child1Entity.class, Child2Entity.class); 
var specification = (root, query, cb) -> {
var inClause = cb.in(root.type());               
  subclasses.forEach(inClause::value);
  return inClause;
}

